# How can I vertically align my div inside another div and keep them side by side?

Tags: html

I've got three divs inside another div.

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="float:right;">
   <div id="childDiv1" style="float:left;">
       <b>Text1</b>
   </div>
   <div id="childDiv2" style="float:left;">
       <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
   </div>
   <div id="childDiv3" style="float:left;">
       <input type='checkbox' />
   </div>
<div>
```

I need them to appear side-by-side, so I've set them as `float:left`.

The trouble is that they appear like this...

[image: Incorrect layout image]

...with the text vertically aligned at the top. I need it to be in the middle.

**N.B.** I've found a post about a [very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446077/how-to-vertically-align-div-inside-another-div-without-displaytable-cell), but it seems that floating causes it to fail.

Comment: The solution you linked to works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Bb4Ye/1/

Comment: @Juhana. No it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/7Fewx/617/

Comment: [Looks ok to me](http://jsfiddle.net/7Fewx/619/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need DIVs, you can use the "***display: inline;***" instead of ***float***. And then ***vertical-align: middle;*** to make the elements centered.

```
    <div id="parentDiv" style=" ">
       <div id="childDiv1" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
           <b>Text1</b>
       </div>
       <div id="childDiv2" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
           <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
       </div>
       <div id="childDiv3" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
           <input type='checkbox' />
       </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I really do need to use DIVs. And that solution is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that easily with tables

```
       <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <b>Text1</b></td>
                <td><img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"></td>
                <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Or you really need to stick with divs? Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Yes. Trouble is these divs are already in a table. And nested tables come with their own issues.

Comment: I see. So how about replacing float with display: inline?

Comment: Yes, good call. I'm upvoting your answer anyway, since it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code: (I advise you to avoid tables as much as possible)

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="float:right;">
   <div id="childDiv1" style="float:left; line-height: 42px;">
       <b>Text1</b>
   </div>
   <div id="childDiv2" style="float:left;">
       <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
   </div>
   <div id="childDiv3" style="float:left; line-height: 42px;">
       <input type='checkbox' />
   </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For them to appear side by side, you don't need them to float, just set them as they are.
As for the image, just add a CSS property for it: `vertical-align:middle` and that should align it in the middle of the text.

Comment: Fine, if that's all you need on your page. If it's not, and the space is limited, they would wrap.

Comment: They would wrap with float too.